# Windows 10 doesn't see my wireless network anymore

Tags: networking, windows-10, wireless-networking

My WiFi router has two networks with different SSIDs, one that broadcasts at 2.4GHz (b/g/n) and one that broadcasts at 5.8GHz (a/c).

I always connect to the 5.8GHz one, because the 2.4GHz one is much slower. That is, until yesterday when my Windows 10 PC just decided the 5.8GHz network doesn't exist anymore! I doesn't give me any errors, the network just doesn't show up in the WiFi networks list!

I tried **EVERYTHING** short of reinstalling Windows itself but it didn't work:

- Tried accessing other networks (the ones that I can see) and they work correctly, both 2.4GHz and 5.8GHz, it's just mine that "disappeared"
- Other devices, like my phone, can still see the 5.8GHz network and connect to it without issues
- Rebooting windows didn't work
- Reinstalling the network adapter drivers didn't work, nor did performing a "network reset" from the windows options
- Restarting the router didn't help
- Changing the network's SSID from the routers options didn't help

I'm out of ideas... why did Windows just "blacklist" my network, and **ONLY** that network? Why can't I see it in the network list while other devices can? How can I diagnose this?

EDIT: update - after further testing, it seems that the issue is somehow tied to the particular USB WiFi adapter I'm using. I switched to a different one and it sees the network. However, I tried the one that doesn't work on a different laptop and there **it works**! So, it's not an issue with the adapter itself, it's an issue that **my Windows installation** together with **that particular adapter**. This is getting weird... anyone has any idea why this could be happening?

Comment: Your troubleshooting steps give no conclusive answer, although it appears you did them correct... Very odd. Have you tried factory resetting the router?

Comment: @acejavelin: thanks for your suggestion, I'll try it, but considering that ALL other devices in my house (phones, laptops, etc.) still see the network and ONLY my desktop pc doesnt, I think it's a PC issue rather than a router issue

Comment: You are probably correct, but before reinstalling Windows I would do it... If it works then you saved a ton of work, if not, you didn't really waste anything but a few minutes of time.

Comment: @acejavelin: I've updated my question with a further test that could shed some light on the problem... or make it even wierder, I don't know which O.o

Comment: Actually, it makes a little more sense... but not a ton more. I would remove that WiFi adapter and then go into the registry and remove every reference to or about it, I believe it is in `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip\Parameters\Interfaces\[Adapter ID]` then reboot and reinstall the adapter and try again. Been a long time since I have had to do this, like XP days I think...

Comment: Is it possible for you to rollback the driver to your USB wifi adapter?

Comment: We are always glad to help but for future reference, the fact that you are utilizing a **USB** WiFi adapter probably should have been included within your original post. That makes a big difference.

Comment: I had this with a bad driver update. so rollback the network card driver

Comment: @acejavelin: thanks for your suggestion, but I can't figure out how to get the "Adapter ID" value, and there are a lot of sub-keys to chose from... where is this information?

Comment: In a command window, use the command `getmac` to get the ID